# What is the mistake in hosting my Angular App?

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm trying to host my Angular project online on Firebase. When I click on the hosting URL I get the following message:

> Welcome
> Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
> You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

There I can only click Open Hosting Documentation. This leads me to the following page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting?hl=de

In a tutorial it was shown that instead I came to my project and above all I try to get to the website where I can see the same as on: http://localhost:4200/

Comment: First you would need to run the following in terminal if you haven't already.
'firebase init' (set up hosting)
Next, 'ng build' (without building you will be deploying an empty project)
Then 'firebase deploy --only hosting' (or you can leave out the --only hosting if you want to deploy everything you setup in init.)

Comment: I did this but i got the same problem